# Where is the \pstverb command documented?

Tags: pstricks

I can find answers to many question on TeX problems here. Mostly they are like giving fish rather than teaching how to fish. One cannot tailor made them  due to short of guide on where they come from. Frequently, later researchers cannot fulfil their curiosity in acquiring knowledge besides solving immediate practical issues.

I have received a nice answer to my question, but now I am puzzled what is `\pstverb` (also `\pstVerb`) and where it is documented; postponed accepting it as "answer" until I fully understand the details. All the documents and search engines point to

> "Driver notes: The command `\pstVerb` must be defined."

or

> "The node macros use `\pstVerb` and \pstverbscale."

I searched documents at [tug.org/PSTricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=packages), in addition to numerous sites and documents on the search engines; as far as I could. I looked into documents inside my installed packages, too, as much it was possible. Appreciate a link.

Comment: According to `texdef`: `\pstverb` is `\special {" #1}`, so it's only a shortcut for stuff which should go verbatim to the postscript driver, unprocessed by LaTeX itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `texdef`,

- `\pstverb` is `\special{" #1}`, meaning that the parameter `#1` is written to the PostScript file, leaving the interpretation and execution of it to PostScript interpreter itself.
  This macro wraps a `gsave-grestore` environment around the content of `#1`, so this is effectively a PostScript group, internal changes are not known outside.
- `\pstVerb` is `\special{ps:#1}` 
  This macro writes to the PostScript as well, but does no changes to origin, scaling, etc.

Additionally there is a command `\pst@Verb`, which is similar to `\pstVerb`, but the code is executed within the `pstricks.pro` dictionary.

The definitions can be found in `pstricks.con`.

Source of this information: *PSTricks* by Herbert Voss, 5th. edition.

Comment: Thanks. I also could find some "ancient" useful hints at http://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb13-3/damrau.pdf

Comment: Sir, Your hint, "\pstverb is \special" guided me to the fact that one puts a piece of code, such as eps wrapped in that point; similar to a pdf. I like to reiterated that your answer was a clear hint to the enquired point.

Comment: @PeterJones: I hope, I could help you.

Comment: Yes sir, that fully helped and solved my problem. Many thanks.